# Passing view model data to javascript - Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

```
// controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();

   viewModel.Title = "It's Alive!!";

   return View(viewModel);
} 

// view
@model Project.Models.IndexViewModel

@section Script {
    <script src="~/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
        var options = {
            title: @Html.Raw(Model.Title)
        }

        application.init(options);
    </script>    
}
```

When the page loads the following error is displayed

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The apostrophe in the string seems to be causing this issue, but i'm not sure how I would resolve this.Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you use **double quote** *(you already use single quote inside string)* and try again? `title: "@Html.Raw(Model.Title)"`

Comment: If you wanting to assign the value of `Model.Title` to a javascript variable, then its `title: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Title))'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  title: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Title))'
```

Comment: Need to be very careful. What if Model.Title == "Someone's page"? In fact, his example includes a ' since it's "It's alive"

Comment: I'm trying to say your answer won't work. If Model.Title is a'b you expand to `title: 'a'b'` which is illegal. The ' needs to be escaped. Your code has the exact problem the OP said he needed help fixing.

Comment: @dman2306, The answer is correct. `title: '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.Title))'` will be `title: "It's Alive!!"` in OP's case - there is nothing illegal about it

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize with [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) before rendering.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json

@section Script {
    <script src="~/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
        var options = {
            title: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Title))
        }

        application.init(options);
    </script>    
}
```

### Output for Double Quote

```
title: "It \"s Alive!!"
```

### Output for Single Quote

```
title: "It 's Alive!!"
```

Comment: I'd even say you want to escape double quotes in Model.Title. In his example there aren't any but logically it could include them.